# In line 0, Expression expected Error (Nand2tetris CPU-emulator)

Tags: nand2tetris

This is not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56336813/expression-expected-error-on-line-1-how-to-fix-it), as I don't have any syntax error -- I only got two lines of code, so I am certain!

[image]

Note:

- I did remember to save `BasicLoop.asm` before attempting to load it.
- I can change the .asm code to whatever I like, the error persists.

Comment: Does loading the same .asm file into cpu emulator, with File->Load program give the same error or is it just with your script?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me a number of times as well.  The first thing to recognize is that the line 0 reference is meaningless.  The problem may be anywhere in your assembly code.

You should look through every line of your assembly code, check that there are no compound commands like:

@SPD=M

when it should be

@SP
D=M

Also, make sure you don't have (@LABEL) instead of just (LABEL).  That could do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the file BasicLoop.asm and then create a new one without using any VM-Translator.

I tried reproducing the error, but it never occured.

The following might be useful if you are developing VM-Translator:

I too got stuck on somewhat similar error saying:
**end of line expected. '0' is found**

While examining my CodeWriter, I found that it wrote `@0`, `@{0}` and on someplaces it combined 2 seperate codes as `0;JMP0` or `0;JMP   D=A`

Hope it helps.